# Possible combinations that can arise in arranging half a Chess set when we get to pick each piece from either colors

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

Let's say we have a full Chess set - 2 Kings (1W, 1B), 4 Knights (2W, 2B), 16 Pawns and so on.

How many ways can we arrange just half a set by picking pieces of either color.
One example arrangement can be:

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BP | WP | WP | BP | BP | WP | WP | WP |
| WR | BN | BB | BQ | WK | WB | WN | WR |

**Legend**:

`W : White` | `B : Black`

`R : Rook` | `B : Bishop` | `N : Knight` | `K : King` | `Q : Queen`

`WR : White Rook` | `BB : Black Bishop`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Isn't it $2^{16}$?

Comment: You should list all the pieces for the benefit of readers who are not familiar with chess sets.

Comment: @Laska that would assume that pieces like the pawns are distinguishable from one another

Comment: It appears that the "half a set" must be arranged with pieces in the same locations that the corresponding white pieces would occupy at the start of a game. That is, the only thing that we can change in the arrangement is the color of the piece in each of the $16$ squares. Is that the question?

Comment: There are three completely different interpretations of your question! 1: the pieces occupy White's starting position, so the answer is $2^{16}=65536$ (@Laska). 2: the pieces can be anywhere, so the answer is...err...not what WarriorOfLegend says :-) 3: it doesn't matter where the pieces are, so the answer is $972$ (Evan Semet). Please clarify!

Answer (score 0):

*This solution takes the assumption that two pieces of the same kind and color are indistinguishable from one another*

As correctly pointed out by someone in the comments below, we are simply decided the number of white pieces that there will be (or black, but it doesn't change the answer) and we can then pick anywhere from 0 to the maximum number of pieces of that kind being white which gives us a total of the number of that type of piece to be chosen +1 different ways to pick each piece.

King: 2

Queen: 2

Bishops: 3

Knights: 3

Rooks: 3

Pawns: 9

This gives us a total of $2^23^39$ = 972 ways

Comment: I don't believe this reasoning is correct. You actually get more than $2^{16}$ arrangements. If pieces of the same kind and color are truly indistinguishable, then the only thing that matters is how many of each color get picked (eg. from 0 to 8 white pawns). Assuming we still pick exactly 8 pawns, 1 king, 1 queen etc.  we get: $(8+1)(1+1)(1+1)(2+1)(2+1)(2+1) = 972$ ways.

Comment: @user3257842 you're right... will fix that now

Comment: I assume pieces of the same type and color are indistinguishable, but I interpret the "arrangement" in the question to identify what piece occupies each of the $16$ squares in the first two ranks on a chessboard. In that case we care not only about how many of the pawns are black, but which squares are occupied by those black pawns.

Answer (score 0):

So we're working on 32 cases of the chessboard. Let's consider the BK. We have 32 cases where we could place him. Now let's consider the WK. There is 31 cases. We keep going, and finally we find 32!. But that's not right, because there is 2 identics Knights, bishops and rooks for each colour, and 8 pawns, so we have to divide the results by 2^6 x 2^6 = 2^12, so i'd say that the answer is 32!/2^12.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses an exponential generating function.

For those who don't know chess, each of the two sides (White and Black) has $1$ King, $1$ Queen, $2$ Bishops, $2$ Knights, $2$ Rooks, and $8$ Pawns, for a total of $16$ pieces.  I'm assuming that pieces of the same type and color are indistinguishable.  We want to find the number of distinct permutations taken from a collection of $16$ pieces. More generally, we might ask what is the number of permutations of $n$ pieces where $0 \le n \le 32$.  The exponential generating function of the number of permutations is
$$f(x) = (1+x)^4 \left(1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 \right)^6 \left(1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \frac{1}{3!} x^3 + \dots + \frac{1}{8!} x^8 \right)^2$$
The number of permutations of $n$ pieces is $n! [x^n]f(x)$, i.e. $n!$ times the coefficient of $x^n$ when $f(x)$ is expanded.  Expanding $f(x)$ would clearly be tedious if done by pencil and paper, but it's easy if you use a computer algebra system.  In the case $n=16$, we find
$$16! [x^{16}]f(x) = 2\;247\;426\;233\;099\;190$$